# Regular Expression to find specific section of a text file

Tags: regex

I want to find a section from text file using regular expression. I have file as below:

```
This is general text section that I don't want.
HEADER:ABC1
This is section text under header
More text to follow 
Additional text to follow
HEADER:XYZ2
This is section text under header
More text to follow 
Additional text to follow
HEADER:KHJ3
This is section text under header 
A match text will look like this A:86::ABC
```

Now, I want to retrieve all section text up to `HEADER` if the section text contains the match `A:86::ABC`. The result text will be

```
(HEADER:KHJ3
This is section text under header 
A match text will look like this A:86::ABC).
```

I appreciate any help. I am using python and the match section can be more than one in a file. Also this is a multi line file.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regex = re.compile(".*(HEADER.*$.*A:86::ABC)", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'HEADER:KHJ3\nThis is section text under header \nA match text will look like this A:86::ABC']
```

Hopefully this helps.
For 2 captures use `".*(HEADER.*$)(.*A:86::ABC)"`

Comment: Thanks! Please and request you to explain the regex.